# Dynamic routing in Angular from Json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

So I have an important Question. Is it possible to achieve async routing in Angular 10 ?
I have read about the AsyncRoute in Angular2, but this one doesn't exist anymore in Angular 10.

My Code looks like this :

```
 getRoutes() {
   return this.http.get(this.APIROOT + 'routes');
 }

pageService.getRoutes().subscribe( (pageRoutes:RouteInterface[]) => {
     const componentMap = {
       'PageComponent': PageComponent,
       'BlogComponent':BlogComponent
     };
     for(let route of pageRoutes){
       this.routes.push({ 'path' : route.route, 'component' : componentMap[route.component]})
     }
   })
```

This will result in an valid and correct :Route Array. My Problem is that this Data isnt synchronous. Its asynchronous. So i cant just push the data to the route:Routes Array in the app-routing.module.ts via the constructor.
Is there any other way to achieve this ? Does anyone has experience with that ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess no one will answer to this Question. So i will answer my Question myself. I have found a solution for the problem. Idk with which language you write your API, but i wrote mine in Python (Django DRF + Wagtail) so i used a signal hook on post_save. Everytime when a Page Model Object is being saved i save all Page Objects into a JSON file. This file will be saved into the Angular Project Directory. From the Directory i will extract the content of the json and do the routes through this method dynamicly.

Here is the Code from my AppComponent :

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked{
  routes:RouteInterface[] = routes;
  routeArr: Routes = [

  ];
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    const componentMap = {
      'PageComponent': PageComponent,
      'BlogComponent':BlogComponent
    };
    for(let route of this.routes){
      this.routeArr.push({ 'path' : route.route, 'component' : componentMap[route.component]})
    }
    console.log(this.routeArr)
    this.router.resetConfig(this.routeArr)
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.router.resetConfig(this.routeArr)
  }

}
```

Thread can be closed.